# Struct and Pointer Segmentation Error in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

can anyone help with this segmentation error i keep getting.  this code is simple but the error is so hard to figure out.

```
struct Link {
  int key;
  unsigned data: 2;
  struct Link *next;
  struct Link *previous;
};

struct Link* addInOrder(struct Link *, struct Link);

int main() {
  struct Link *head;
  struct Link data1;
  struct Link data2;
  struct Link data3;
  data1.key = 25;
  data1.data = 1;
  data1.next = NULL;
  data2.key = 50;
  data2.data = 0;
  data2.next = NULL;
  data3.key = 100;  
  data3.data = 2; 
  data3.next = NULL;
  head = NULL;
  head = addInOrder(head, data2);
}

struct Link* addInOrder(struct Link *srt, struct Link l) {
  if(!srt) {
    return &l;
  }

  struct Link *temp = srt;
  while(temp->next && l.key > temp->key)
    temp = temp->next;

  printf("here\n");

  if(l.key > temp->key) {
    printf(" 1\n");
    temp->next = &l;
    l.previous = temp;
  }
  else {
    printf(" 2\n");
    l.previous = temp->previous;
    l.next = temp;
    printf( "2.2\n");
    if(temp->previous) {
      //printf("%i\n",temp->previous->key);
      temp->previous->next = &l;
    }
    printf(" 2.3\n");
    temp->previous = &l;
  }
  return srt;
}
```

i keep getting an error at the first line in addInOrder().  all the compiler says is Segmentation Error.

Edit: also, if i add *printf("...");* right after the if statement and run it ... does not print

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the second argument of `addInOrder()` by value (`struct Link l`).  This creates a copy of the argument when you call the function, and in `addInOrder()`, `l` exists on the stack.  You're then returning the address of the local variable and assigning it to `head`, but when the function exits, that variable is out of scope and is deallocated.  So you're assigning an invalid address to `head`, and that results in a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

The part (and everywhere `&l` is used)

```
if (!srt)
    return &l;
```

is returning the address of a stack variable.
Your `addInOrder` function should probably have the signature

```
struct Link* addInOrder(struct Link* srt, struct Link* l);
```

Comment: And then change all the struct references within the function (`l.whatever`) to pointer references (`l->whatever`).

Comment: hey james,  if that doesnt work without changing main() than i must find another solution

Comment: @user1774515 The only thing you have to change in `main` is the line `head = addInOrder(head, &data2);` (change it to that). You'll have to make a couple of other changes in the body of `addInOrder` too, like @JimStewart pointed out. Just fix the compilation errors one by one from the top.

Comment: yeah i know i would have to change main, but im not allowed to change any part of main.

Comment: @user1774515 Why not, I don't see how it can work otherwise. Are you sure you copied it correctly? You only have to change one character in `main`.

Comment: yeah its for an assignment.  i created a new struct link using malloc and sets its values to that of l and then everything worked